# Maintain the odd/even table style after hiding tr from table

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've created a JS function that filters specific rows in the table away, but since It's only a hide/show filter, the `odd/even` rows gets mixed up.

This is how my JS filter works.

```js
var hide_info_checkbox = document.getElementById("hide_info");
var hide_debug_checkbox = document.getElementById("hide_debug");

hide_info_checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var info_td = document.getElementsByClassName("info");
  if (this.checked) {
    for (var i = 0; i < info_td.length; i++) {
      info_td[i].classList.add("ftp_hide_row");
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < info_td.length; i++) {
      info_td[i].classList.remove("ftp_hide_row");
    }
  }
});

hide_debug_checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  debug_td = document.getElementsByClassName("debug");
  if (this.checked) {
    for (var i = 0; i < debug_td.length; i++) {
      debug_td[i].classList.add("ftp_hide_row");
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < debug_td.length; i++) {
      debug_td[i].classList.remove("ftp_hide_row");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/*
    FTP styling
*/

.ftp_table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.ftp_table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
}

.ftp_hide_row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="hide_info" name="hide_info" value="hide_info">
<label for="hide_info"> Hide INFO</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="hide_debug" name="hide_debug" value="hide_debug">
<label for="hide_debug"> Hide DEBUG</label>
<table class="ftp_table" id="ftp_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Log</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="info">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:15.946 INFO [conftest:101] -------------- Global Fixture Setup Started --------------</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="debug">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:16.009 DEBUG [Geni:37] Initializing </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="info">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:16.059 INFO [ArtifactoryWrapper:21] Downloading</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="info">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:16.061 INFO [ArtifactHandler:55] Art</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="debug">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:16.063 DEBUG [SessionManager:84] GET</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="debug">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:16.070 DEBUG [connectionpool:227] Starting new HTTP connection (1)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="debug">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:17.422 DEBUG [connectionpool:452] 200 None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="info">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:17.561 INFO [SessionManager:52] No application/json Content-Type header in GET response</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="debug">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:17.422 DEBUG [connectionpool:452] 200 None</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, the `odd/even` gets mixed up, since I only add a class which hides the rows, and doesn't delete them:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this, so the odd/even is as expected?

Comment: By the way what is the `odd/even` style here. I am not getting it

Comment: No-one is gonna read that all code. Provide, minimum code that refers your problem!

Comment: @Deadpool That's 26 lines of (of duplicated) JS, even less CSS and some markup. One can argue that half of the JS and markup could be removed without losing information, but you won't die while reading through all of it o.O

Comment: @Rana Odd/even styling is when alternate rows are different colours, like [old computer printout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_stationery#/media/File:Endlospapier_fan-fold_paper.jpg).

Comment: Ohh.. thanks @AndrewMorton, OP is asking in this sense. As OP hasn't tried a bit about it, so thought might be other concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a JS version

I delegated your checkbox too

```js
const table = document.getElementById("ftp_table");
const zebra = table => table.querySelectorAll('tr:not([hidden])')
   .forEach((tr, i) => tr.classList.toggle("grey",i % 2 === 0));

document.getElementById("checks").addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const id = tgt.id;
  if (tgt && id.startsWith("hide")) {
    const chk = tgt.checked;
    const whichClass = id.replace("hide_", ""); // info or debug
    [...document.getElementsByClassName(whichClass)]
      .forEach(row => row.hidden = chk);
    zebra(table);
  }
});
zebra(table)
```

```css
/*
    FTP styling
*/

.ftp_table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
.grey {background-color: #d8d8d8; }
```

```html
<div id="checks">
  <input type="checkbox" id="hide_info" name="hide_info" value="hide_info">
  <label for="hide_info"> Hide INFO</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hide_debug" name="hide_debug" value="hide_debug">
  <label for="hide_debug"> Hide DEBUG</label>
</div>
<table class="ftp_table" id="ftp_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Log</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="info">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:15.946 INFO [conftest:101] -------------- Global Fixture Setup Started --------------</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="debug">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:16.009 DEBUG [Geni:37] Initializing </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="info">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:16.059 INFO [ArtifactoryWrapper:21] Downloading</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="info">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:16.061 INFO [ArtifactHandler:55] Art</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="debug">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:16.063 DEBUG [SessionManager:84] GET</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="debug">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:16.070 DEBUG [connectionpool:227] Starting new HTTP connection (1)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="debug">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:17.422 DEBUG [connectionpool:452] 200 None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="info">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:17.561 INFO [SessionManager:52] No application/json Content-Type header in GET response</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="debug">
      <td>2021-10-06 12:38:17.422 DEBUG [connectionpool:452] 200 None</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Awsome it works, but I have some questions :) This part `tr.style.backgroundColor = i % 2 === 0 ? "#d8d8d8" : "white"` is just for the `odd/even` coloring yes? but how does the even listener work? how does it know when it's the class `info / debug`

Comment: sorry i just made an edit to the question, but how do you know when to show `debug rows` and `info rows`

Comment: See updated expanded code. `[...document.getElementsByClassName(id.replace("hide_", ""))`  will select info or debug based on hide_info and hide_debug, I just remove the `hide_`

Comment: Aaaah i see, smart! so you listen for a checkbox change, and if there is one then `remove hide_` and set the class' with the name `debug/info` to be hidden `check/notchecked`. Then `zebra(table)` is called `onchange` and `onload` to refresh the table `odd/even`?